# Помогите нарисовать в turtle. Python

Tags: python, графика, turtle

Мне нужно нарисовать следующий рисунок на `turtle`:
[image: Рисунок должен выглядеть примерно так]

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: 2 вопроса за час, вы хоть сами то пытаться собираетесь?
освойте черепашку что ли - ну не сложный инструмент же

Comment: в практической 15 задач и 2 я не понимаю как сделать

Comment: чуть соложнее рисунки пошли и я не могу разобраться

Comment: @Микита в другом вопросе я подсказал, вероятно, сложный момент - на сколько нужно поворачивать - но что-то не видно, чтобы вы прочитали и отреагировали

Comment: @MBo согласен полностью

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если цель - создать такой же рисунок, то вот код:

```py
import turtle

x = 100
#рисует повёрнутую черепашку посередине
center_turtle = turtle.Turtle('turtle')
center_turtle.right(150)
#рисует центральную слева черепашку
ml_turtle = turtle.Turtle('turtle') #middle left
ml_turtle.left(180)
ml_turtle.forward(x)
#создаёт списки черепашек для верхней и нижней половины
up_turtles = [turtle.Turtle('turtle') for _ in range(5)]
down_turtles = [turtle.Turtle('turtle') for _ in range(5)]
#рисует верхнюю половину
for i, trt in enumerate(up_turtles): turtle
    trt.left(180)
    trt.right((i+1)*30)
    trt.forward(x)
#рисует нижнюю половину
for i, trt in enumerate(down_turtles):
    trt.left(180)
    trt.left((i+1)*30)
    trt.forward(x)
turtle.exitonclick()
```

Результат точь-в-точь.
P.S. Для каждой черепашки кроме тех что в цикле своя переменная.

> освойте черепашку что ли - ну не сложный инструмент же - @Жихар

EDIT: x - длина линий, ведь я не могу её определить по картинке.

Comment: а как можно убрать черепашку в середине?

Comment: она есть на картинке, поэтому добавил. Если не надо, комментариями код подписан, убираешь ненужные компоненты. В данном случае строки 4 - 6 включительно.

Comment: понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Всё ещё проще:

```
from turtle import *
shape("turtle")
right(180)
for i in range(11):
    left(150)
    fd(100)
    stamp()
    right(180)
    fd(100)
done()
```